# JQuery get HTML of table except some TDs

Tags: jquery, html

if I have below table

```
<table>
 <tr>
   <td>Name</td>
   <td>Age</td>
   <td class='remove'>Age <input type=checkbox  title='Select All' /> </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>Na11</td>
   <td>11</td>
   <td class='remove'><input type=checkbox   /></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>Name</td>
   <td>Age</td>
   <td class='remove'>Age <input type=checkbox   /></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

How can I get the html of this table except for TD which has class as "remove". I wish not to use

```
.remove()
```

because I do not need to change the display on the browser. I need only the HTML.

is below correct

```
$('table :not(.remove)').html();
```

but this does not give me the html for the table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may have to clone the element first

```
$('table').clone().find('.remove').remove().end().html();
```

if the html need to include the `table` tag also then

```
$('table').clone().find('.remove').remove().end()[0].outerHTML;
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/aA6UL/)

Comment: Is there a way without using .clone()

Comment: @ArunP-Jonny why wouldn't this `$('table :not(.remove)').html();` work

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
 var html1 = $('table').find('.remove').remove().end().html();
 $('#t1').text(html1);
 var html2 = $('table').find('.remove').remove().end()[0].outerHTML;
 $('#t2').text(html2);
```

there is no need to clone if you want to change in same .

Comment: this will remove the items from the display.